# How can i build a loading script for my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i built my own slideshow, i didn't want to download a library because I just want to show a full background image, and a description.

My slideshow is already built. Now I need to create a loading script, because I will insert big images.

Can you guys give me any idea of how can i change my code?

The slideshow must start when the images are all loaded.

I tried to use on load, but it still not working.

Here my code:

```
var pics = ["http://www.geant.net/Resources/PartnerResources/Partner%20Resources%20Image%20Library/Image%2010_958642.jpg",
    "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"
];

var descriptions = ["Description number 1",
    "Description number 2"
];

function displaySlideshow(pics) {

    var i = 1;
    setInterval(
        function() {
            $("body, #resp-background").css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + pics[i] + ')',
                '-webkit-transition': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out',
                'transition': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out;',
                '-moz-transition': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out;',
                'background-size': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out;',
                '-o-background-size': 'cover',
                '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
                '-webkit-background-size': 'cover'
            });

            $('.s-description').html(descriptions[i]);
            i++;
            if (i >= pics.length) i = 0;

        }, 4200);
}


displaySlideshow(pics);
```

Jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kx1fgsox/

Comment: You need to preload the images, using `new Image()`. Keep a counter on their onloads. If the counter reaches the picture array length fire of the slideshow Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pics = ["http://www.geant.net/Resources/PartnerResources/Partner%20Resources%20Image%20Library/Image%2010_958642.jpg",
    "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"
];

var counter = 0
function preLoader()
{
            tempImage = [];
            $('.s-description').html("Preloading images...");
    for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++)
    {
        var tempImage.push(new Image());
        tempImage[tempImage.length-1].onload = loadImageComplete;
        tempImage[tempImage.length-1].src = pics[i];
    }
}

function loadImageComplete()
{
    counter++;
    if (counter == pics.length)
    {
                    $('.s-description').html("");
        displaySlideshow(pics);
    }
}
preLoader();
```

This code will do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kx1fgsox/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to catch an event for the loading of a background image. Also, using a background-image is creating the effect of tiling the image, on my screen. This might not be the effect you intented.

Instead of background images, what I recommend is inserting actual `img` elements into the `div`, like this:

```
var prevImg = $(".slideshow img").first();
var newImg = $("<img src=" + pics[i] + "></img>");

$('.slideshow').fadeOut();
$('.slideshow img').remove();
$('.slideshow').append(newImg);
newImg.load(function() { $('.slideshow').fadeIn(); });
```

That way, the slideshow fades out, as you intended, and does not fade back in until the image is loaded.

You will need a bit of CSS to make this work, however:

```
.slideshow
{
    width: 100%;
}

.slideshow img
{
    width: 100%;
}
```